# submit form after Ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have very little experience with Ajax and could use some help. I have an Ajax function (below), and was wondering if it's possible to submit an HTML form after where the Ajax call hit's "success". I've also included the button that fires the function.

```
<div class="buttons">
<div class="pull-right">
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'index.php?route=payment/cheque/confirm',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
        },
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have read a few other answers but didn't really understand what was going on. If someone could make it simple I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

here is the form:

```
<form name="purchase_form" method="post" action="https://www3.eigendev.com/mirapay/secure_credit.php">

<input type="hidden" name="MTID" value="<?= $mtid ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="Merchant_ID" value="f5b23eea8cf2e5db3af9845f44e1aacd">
<input type="hidden" name="MKEY" value="<?= $mKey ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="SuccessURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="FailURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="EMail" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="Amount1" value="<?= $total ?>">

</form>
```

Comment: Do you want the form to submit data to the server or do you want it to redirect?

Comment: The form redirects to an external site and submits values to that site. I'll up up a sample.

Comment: there is no reason for you to submit it. you have already made your ajax request. after its done then just continue to what you need to do

Comment: So  maybe take out:  success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }

and it will just stay on the page. That sort of the idea?

Comment: where is $button_confirm and $continue came from?